# Is there a mistake in the solution given to this exercise?(compact linear operators)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, operator-theory, compactness

The exewrcise is:

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space, with an
>   orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$ and let $T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.
>   Show that if T is compact then $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\|Te_n\|=0$.

Here is the solution given:

[image]

But I am wondering how they get the inequality given. It seems there is some sort of the triangle inequality. We have that for every n(r): $\|y\| \le \|y-Te_{n(r)}\|+\|Te_{n(r)}\|$. So $\|\frac{1}{r}Te_{n(r)}\|\ge \frac{1}{r}\|y\|-\frac{1}{r^2}$. Together this gives that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\|\frac{1}{r}Te_{n(r)}\|\ge \sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{r}\|y\|-\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{r^2}$. But this is not quite what they have, they have the norm outside the sum in the first part: $\|\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{r}Te_{n(r)}\|\ge \sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{r}\|y\|-\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac{1}{r^2}$, how can they have gotten this form, where the norm is outside the sum?

Comment: Because $\{ e_n \}$ is orthonormal, then $(Te_n,x)=(e_n,T^{\star}x)$ converges to $0$ for all $x$. Therefore, if $\{ Te_{n_k} \}$ converges converges to some $y$, then $(y,x)=0$ for all $x$, which means $y=0$. Am I missing something?